# Is it possible to catch an Objective-C error from Swift code?

Tags: objective-c, swift, exception

I would like to do something like:

```
try {
    SomeObjectiveClass.someMethod()
catch Error {
    print("Recovered objc crash from Swift!")
}
```

I'm building an app where I type some visual constraints and I get the result or a message about any mistake.

Now, every time I type wrong constraints the app crashes, but I'd like to display a dialog with the error and let the user try again.

In my situation I don't have the "NSError-to-throws" automatic translation.

Comment: Yes, if `someMethod` takes an `NSError **` parameter, when you call that from Swift 2, that behaves like a method that throws an error.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Only in those cases? What about a wrong constraint that makes my layout code crash. Could I catch that?

Comment: No, that's an exception, which is a different issue. You should generally resolve exceptions in the development process (e.g. fix the source of your constraints-based exception), rather than trying to catch them. The `do`-`try`-`catch` mechanism in Swift is for catching errors, not exception handling.

Comment: I know, Rob, but I want to catch them because I'm building a program where I type some visual constraints and I get the result or a message about any mistake. It's not a "normal" application where you should never have wrong constraints.

Comment: Then, as the documentation says, "Any exception handling behavior must be implemented in Objective-C code used by Swift."

Comment: Damn it. Thanks Rob! :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this class:

```
@implementation SomeObjectiveClass

+ (BOOL)someClassMethodWithError:(NSError **)error {
    // some something that 

    if (everythingOk) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (error) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kMyDomain code:kSomeErrorCode userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"Some error message"}];
        }
        return false;
    }
}

- (BOOL)someInstanceMethodWithError:(NSError **)error {
    // some something that 

    if (everythingOk) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (error) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kMyDomain code:kSomeOtherErrorCode userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"Some error message"}];
        }
        return false;
    }
}

@end
```

You can then catch those errors like so:

```
do {
    try SomeObjectiveClass.someClassMethod()

    // or

    let object = SomeObjectiveClass()
    try object.someInstanceMethod()
} catch {
    print("Recovered \(error) from Swift!")
}
```

Note, this catching of errors should not be confused with exception handling which we used to be able to do in Objective-C. Exceptions should be eliminated during the development process. The above is for legitimate runtime errors (e.g. failed network request or some other error that might occur due to conditions outside of the programmer's control).

To quote from [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10):

> Although Swift error handling resembles exception handling in Objective-C, it is entirely separate functionality. If an Objective-C method throws an exception during runtime, Swift triggers a runtime error. There is no way to recover from Objective-C exceptions directly in Swift. Any exception handling behavior must be implemented in Objective-C code used by Swift.